# How can I load custom font (ttf) with size more than 60kb

Tags: blackberry, custom-font

I want to load custom font with size 150kb, but I it gets EXCEEDS_LIMIT error and in the code that below console prints "EXCEEDS_LIMIT", I tried to reduce the ttf size but I failed
Any Idea??

```
    LabelField helloWorld = new LabelField("Hello World");
    int res = FontManager.getInstance().load("PageD1.TTf", "MyFont",
            FontManager.EXCEEDS_LIMIT);
    if (res == FontManager.SUCCESS) {
        try {
            FontFamily family = FontFamily.forName("MyFont");
            Font myFont = family.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 50);
            helloWorld.setFont(myFont);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } else if (res == FontManager.EXCEEDS_LIMIT) {
        System.out.println("EXCEEDS_LIMIT");
    }

    add(helloWorld);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FontManager.html#load) there is a limit in place of 60kb for OS 5.0. There is no way to work around this.

Under OS 6.0 the limit remains the  same, but under 7.0 it is raised to [6MB](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FontManager.html#load)

Comment: Yes, I know this documentation, and unfortunately I currently develop for OS 5,6, any idea?

Comment: No, you really don't have any options.  I actually had to go so far as to create a custom bitmap font renderer for my app, allowing me to generate fonts of multiple sizes.  That's not practical for most situations though.